# How can I visualization (Plot) Non-sequence DateTime in two columns data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot, time-series

I have a dataset for taxi trip information for four years (2010-2013). I want to do some preliminary data analysis by looking at plots of each value in two columns in a data with 'Day Hours' on the x axis in increments of 1-24 or 0-23 'Trip Duration (seconds)' on the y-axis. The problem is the `pickup_hour` column is not sequential, it's based on datetime column.

```
>>df10.head(20)
```

[First 20 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J34Af.png)
Then, I was tried to plot data as following as:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 7))
plt.plot(df10['pickup_hour'][0:10],df10[' trip_time_in_secs'][0:10])
plt.xlabel('Day Hours')
plt.ylabel('Trip Duration (seconds)')
#plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

[Plot for first 10 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8xE2.png)

Now I hope to find some way to help please, thanks advance.

Comment: if you want a plot like this you should plot each day separately. and for that i think there data is not frequent enough. for example the first day only has one record

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply, but my dataset for a specific area like (from A to B) only, not for all trips in a day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot all the days in the same diagram, then don't draw the lines. Just mark them with an 'x' or 'o'

```
plt.plot(df10['pickup_hour'][0:10],df10[' trip_time_in_secs'][0:10],'x')
```

you can set the X-axis labels using

```
plt.xticks(range(24))
```

Comment: "Thanks". Now I did it when the values range ([0:20]) it's ok, but I get some float numbers in hours bar (X-Axis) when values range in ([0:50]) or more.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean.. you have decimal points in the data set? Just convert then to int

Comment: no all data (int), but  (X-Axis) was shown like (5.0 7.5 10.0 12.5 15.0 17.5 20.0), that is Day Hours (Axis)

Comment: you mean the labels?

Comment: Yes Yes, so with this data, I can't use a plotline graph?

Comment: that is what u did before right, that is the kind of graph you will get.. or else u have to sort the data

Comment: But I can't sort the data, because of (hour column) depend on DateTime, if I sort it the dataset will be merged or (damage) or (meaningless).

Comment: exactly my point.. so just plot the points.. since you time is divided in to fixed intervals plotting the lines is useless anyway.. where there is more data most of the line will overlap on one vertical line